# Not able to save the values coming from the properties file in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to save the value fetched from a properties file in my jenkins pipeline but it is not working

```
 script {
                    String content = readFile("gradle.properties")

                    Properties properties = new Properties()
                    properties.load(new StringReader(content))

                   backupVersion = ${properties.backupUrl} // this is not working
                    echo backupVersion
                   echo "property 'version' has value '${properties.backupUrl}'"// this is working
                }
```

I have defined backupVersion globally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't use dollar syntax if you directly refer to variables. Dollar syntax is only for [string interpolation](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/#_string_interpolation).

Simply write:

```
backupVersion = properties.backupUrl
```